# Next.js error 500 (Internal Server Error) - API routing in local

Tags: next.js, auth0, next.js13

Working in my local environment I'm getting an error when I try to run a file within my `/pages/api/` folder.

When my sidebar component loads it makes a request to the routing api and this is triggering the error saying it can't be found.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const ChatSidebar = ({ chatId }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadChatList = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/chat/getChatList`, {
        method: "POST",
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log("CHAT LIST: ", json);
    };
    loadChatList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-900 text-white">
      <Link href="/api/auth/logout">
        Logout
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see the error in the console - highlighting the row in getChatList that includes the line:

```
const response = await fetch(`/api/chat/getChatList`, {
```

[image: Output from the cons]

The component is called from a file in the following path `pages/chat/[[...chatid]].js` and the path (`/api/chat/getChatList`) matches the folder structure.

[image: File structure]

I'm using Auth0 and my callback is set correctly to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback` and I'm logged in. My api is functioning with the other items in the folder (e.g. sendMessage.js).

My authentication is checked in the index.js page and routes to the chat page when authenticated. My index.js page:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';
import { getSession } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default function Home() {
  const {isLoading, error, user} = useUser();

  if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if(error) return <div>{error.message}</div>
  
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Login or Sign up</title>
      </Head>
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen w-full bg-gray-800 text-white text-center">
        <div className="">
          {!!user && <Link href="/api/auth/logout" className="btn">Logout</Link>}
          {!user && (
            <>
              <Link href="/api/auth/login" className="btn">Login</Link>
              <Link href="/api/auth/signup" className="btn">Sign up</Link>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// checking for a user session - if the session exists user is logged in and we redirect to chat
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const session = await getSession(ctx.req, ctx.res);
  if (!!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/chat",
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```